# Calculation of an average plane without using a covariance matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, 3d, vectors

I need to calculate the normal to an average plane using the positions of >3 points (for 3 points, I know how to do it with a cross-product). My main problem is that it needs to be a simple method without covariance matrices. It is for an Awk script and there is no library for fitting or matrix operations.

My idea would be:

1. Calculate the cross-products between every possible combination of 3 points from a set of say, 10 points.
2. Calculate the average cross-product.

Would that give me the normal to the average plane (or be a good approximation)? It may not be an elegant method, but it is easy and fast and Awk can do it.

Cheers

Comment: By average plane do you mean least squares plane? Or something else?

Comment: I think so. Would there be another type of average/mean plane?

Comment: The problem with your idea is that changing the order in which you take the three points flips the sign of the cross product. So you will get lots of cross products of opposite signs, and on averaging they will cancel out and you'll be left with approximately zero.

Comment: Yes but in my case it won't matter as the second step will be to calculate a dot product to get $\cos^2\theta$ with $\theta$ the angle between the normal and the vector (0,0,1). So whether I average over all the possible normal vectors or other all the $\cos^2\theta$ shouldn't matter... I guess.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach may be valid, although it depends on the distribution of points. You should be aware, that the cross products might be antiparallel, this at least should be corrected.

To find a point on the plane use the average of the points themselves, their "center of mass".

Comment: The distribution of the points may be quite random. If the approach sounds valid, then I may give it a go.